# Error while Executing OPENQUERY with Oracle 10g in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle10g, openquery

- Linked Server Name:CBSLINKED   //Oracle 10g
- Name of Database if oracle : CBSIVRDB
- Name of Stored Procedure : FIU_INSERT
- having parameter as (FromDate,ToDate)
- My DB: SQL server R2

> execute  ('call CBSIVRDB.FIU_INSERT (''
>   TO_DATE(''01-JUN-2014'',DD-MMM-YYYY)
>   '',''TO_DATE(''30-JUN-2014'',DD-MMM-YYYY)'') ') at CBSLINKED

**Error:**

> OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "CBSLINKED" returned message "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Comment: You are missing the '' in front of DD-MMM. But here might be more problems though.

Comment: you mean like this 'DD-MMM-YYYY'

Comment: I have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CBSIVRDB.FIU_INSERT (TO_DATE(''01-JUN-2014'',''DD-MON-YYYY''),TO_DATE(''30-JUN-2014'',''DD-MON-YYYY''))
```

or more precisely

```
execute ('call CBSIVRDB.FIU_INSERT (TO_DATE(''01-JUN-2014'',''DD-MON-YYYY''),TO_DATE(''30-JUN-2014'',''DD-MON-YYYY''))') at CBSLINKED
```

Comment: OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "CBSLINKED" returned message "ORA-01821: date format not recognized
".